# checkbox - input inside label doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a working checkbox:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch mt-3 ml-4"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id='G1'> 
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="G1">TEXT</label>
</div>
```

But I assign the id later via jQuery and that's why I am looking for a way to use a checkbox without the `for=""` attribute like:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch mt-3 ml-4"> 
  <label class="custom-control-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="G1"> Test 
  </label> 
</div>
```

By clicking on the checkbox, the checkbox fires but the the button doesn't switch between ON/OFF. What do I miss? Or is there another way to use the `for` attribute with something like `for="this.id"`?

I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Can youu post the script aswell as a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the id through jQuery, then setting the "for" attribute at the same time should be easy enough; assuming you've only got one element with that class, this jQuery will work (otherwise you'll need to alter the selector to suit):-

```
var input = $('.custom-control-input');
input.attr('id', 'G1');
var label = input.closest('.custom-control-label');
label.attr('for', 'G1');
```